# Where is my Android device mounted inside my Linux?

Tags: mount, android, fuse, mtp, gvfs

I am trying to run a bash script on certain folder inside an Android phone, mounted in my Fedora Linux box. I can see that the phone is there with `adb devices` (no, I do not want to use ADB for this!), I can see the phone folders using `dolphin`, I can even see that the phone is there with `mount`, showing:

```
 kio-fuse on /run/user/500/kio-fuse-JhdSvC type fuse.kio-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=500,group_id=500)
```

Yet, the folders `/run/user/500/kio-fuse-JhdSvC`, `/run/user/500/gvfs`, `/run/user/500/gvfsd` and `~/.gvfs` are all empty, even when I see the folders in Dolphin.

I also tried to mount the phone as I used to, with the command `simple-mtpfs -o allow_root -o enable-move /mnt/phone`, but I get:

```
LIBMTP PANIC: Trying to dump the error stack of a NULL device
```

So: how can I know in which folder in my filesystem the thing is mounted? Why is the folder `/run/user/500/kio-fuse-JhdSvC` empty?

**EDIT**: Following [this advice](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/mpiq0i/prevent_kde_from_handling_mtp/) I am able to prevent KDE from automouting the Android Device as mtp. Yet, the popup in the phone to "Allow USB..." disappears as soon as it appears, so I cannot click on it.